# Insert checkboxes into table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have created a `WYSIWYG` 'document' creator which posts into its own table called doc_list, this table is associated with a `category` table , `cat_list` and there is a `JOIN` table which collects the `ID` of both the category and document. However, when creating the document I want to be able to use the checkbox to show the available categories and when you select them for it to update the join table by taking the id of the doc and the `category/categories` you have selected it to belong to.

Here are my tables:

```
cat_list (id,cat_title)

doc_list (id, doc_title)

cat_doc_link_table (id, link_doc_id, link_cat_id)
```

Here is my document creation form:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php 

require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

try{
    // Selecting entire row from cat_list table
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cat_list");

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$cat = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<form action="actions/newDocAdd.php" method="post" id="rtf" name="">
    <input type="text" name="doc_title" id="doc_title" required="required" placeholder="Document Title"/><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" class="selectall"/> Select all</label>

<div id="checkboxlist">


<?php
    foreach($cat as $cat){ 
?>

        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $cat["cat_id"]; ?>" name="cat_no"><?php echo $cat["cat_title"]; ?></a><br>

    <?php
    }
?>  


</div> 

<br>

    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ibold()" title="Bold Text"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iitalic()" title="Italic Text"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iunderline()" title="Underline Text"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontName()" title="Font Family"><i class="fa fa-font"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontsize()" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ifontcolor()" title="Font Colour"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ihiliteColor()" title="Highlight Text"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ilink()" title="Add/Edit Link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="iunlink()" title="Remove Link"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyLeft()" title="Text align-left"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyCenter()" title="Text align-center"><i class="fa fa-align-center"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onclick="ijustifyRight()" title="Text align-right"><i class="fa fa-align-right"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iUnorderedList()" title="Unordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtn" type="button" onClick="iOrderedList()" title="Ordered List"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtnUndo" type="button" onClick="iUndo()" title="Undo last change"><i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></button>
    <button class="postEditBtnRedo" type="button" onClick="iRedo()" title="Redo last change"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></button>


    <br><br>

    <textarea name="doc_content" id="doc_content" placeholder="Document Content" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name="editor" id="editor" style="width:100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>

    <br><br> 
    <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Create Document" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

And here is the action script:

```
<?
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
       header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
include_once'../../config.php';

try {



$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$sql = "INSERT INTO doc_list (doc_title, doc_content, doc_created, user_id, cat_no) VALUES ('".$_POST["doc_title"]."','".$_POST["doc_content"]."',NOW(), '".$_SESSION['user']."','".$_POST['cat_no']."')";

    print_r($_POST);

if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
    header ('Location: ../docList.php?success=1');
}
else{
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Comment: In your action script you just have an insert for the doc_list table. If you want to add information to the cat_doc_list table you also need an insert for that. Am I misinterpreting what you asked?

Comment: Kinda, unless I am approaching it incorrectly? So on the form to create a new doc I am calling in the available categories into the form, now what I want to be able to do is select those categories and it associates the categories to that doc I have created and that is where the JOIN table does the work

Comment: For a start I would use radio buttons and not check boxes as you are only inserting one row.

Comment: Would that work for inserting this into multiple categories though?

Comment: Not with your present insert statement

Comment: That's why I need some assistance with changing the approach, I need the facility to be able post in an array to a join table which detects which checkboxes have been selected and associate them with the doc_id which the id of the information being submitted